# Bash - Как скопировать файл трижды, чтобы к ним приписывались префиксы?

Tags: linux, bash

Файл должен быть трижды скопирован в указаную директорию с числовыми префиксами в имени файла; например, `1_file`, `2_file`, `3_file`. Путь к директории передается вторым параметром.

Comment: отличное задание. вы его кому даёте?

Answer (score 1):

## Пример

**1.** Создать файл `command.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for (( i = 1; i <= $3; i++ ))
do
  cp $1 $2$i"_"$(basename $1)
done
```

**2.** Сделать его исполняемым:

```sh
chmod +x command.sh
```

**3.** Запустить:

```sh
./command.sh ./a.txt ./ 3
```

Comment: Если уж используете возможности самого. shell, то используйте их до конца, а именно замените `basename` на встроенные варианты с выделением подстроки.

Comment: Далее, у вас попущении разделитель между каталогом и файлом. В довесок, может случится так, что каталог + файл выйдут за рамки допустимых ограничений на длину пути, поэтому нужно канонизировать путь перед использованием.

Comment: Ну и в качестве вишенки на торте, попробуйте вместо `cp` использовать `ln`.

Comment: @0andriy, вы можете исправить мой ответ или дать свой.

Comment: Если бы ваш ответ был совсем плохим, я бы так и сделал. Однако я не собираюсь плодить сущности без необходимости (бритва Оккама). Поэтому поправив ваш ответ, можно получить лучший результат. Да и негоже человеку с таким рейтингом так упираться, цель этого сайта не в показе гордыни, а в попытке дать качественную информацию.